# CSS - using .left and .right classes

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the past I've always set up my style sheets with '.left' and '.right' classes.

However having read lots of articles recently, I now realise this isn't good practice - what if I want to change one of those '.left' divs and float it right? I'd have to change the HTML.

Would I instead be better off declaring floats every time I want to use it ( #content {padding: 6px; float: left;} ).

If anyone can shed some light on what's the best practice for this, it'd be great for future developments.

Comment: A good way to think about this is to consider the case where you may end up wanting different layouts for desktop and mobile. Say left and right on a desktop, but one beneath the other on mobile. You should have the same HTML in both cases, so 'left' and 'right' would clearly be inappropriate for mobile. Choose your class names to describe the content, not the layout, and choose your CSS selectors with care to bind your presentation to your markup as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need.

Using `.left` and `.right` classes (and other similar classes like `.clearfix`) is often more efficient since you declare them only once in your style file, decreasing its size.

On the other side, if you plan to make some redesigns to your page in the future, it is more flexible to use *semantic* classes, to totally separate the style from the `html`. This strategy makes the changes easier. To know more about this check [this link](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/).

Answer (score 0):

The classes .left and .right can be handy especially if your html code is generated, for example by a CMS. However, if you feel like the float might change soon and you write your code manually, you can setup the class and an id. If you then give #yourID a `float: right;`, it will overwrite a `float:left;` coming from .left class. This is not really clean version but you won't have to define the #yourID rule right away unless you need it. In many CMS systems, each content element will get an id="content-element-12346" or something like that by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `.left` and `.right` classes as utilities rather than using them continuously.

So use use them for all elements that need them. But when there is the odd occasion that you may need the float something left or right use the utility classes.